# A riley A riley

Tags: affix-riddle

Duplicate me!

> Japanese tea to begin,
>
> Atlas Obscura to be in the middle,
>
> A computer at the end.

Together I Duplicate me!

(everything, including errors, are purposeful!)

HINT:

> Duplicate answers are acceptable, just double it on Google!

Comment: I'm thinking about memes and obviously I'm thinking about the Loss meme :/

Comment: Would it be correct to think about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_Chaos) in regards to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_Chaos_(album))?

Comment: Or, am I completely off track?

Comment: @Stevo yesn’t. Wrong C. chaos

Comment: And also, it’s from the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NOT SO PARTIAL ANSWER:

Japanese tea to begin:

> CHA (tea in japanese)

Atlas Obscura to be in the middle:

> AO (Atlas Obscura initials)

A computer at the end:

> OS (as in Operating System of a computer)

Together, they spell:

> Chaos!

UPDATE:

If I duplicate that first part, I get:

> *[Chaos chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_(genus))*, a genus of Amoebas, with a history of having its scientific name mixed up with other genera and causing further *chaos*.

Comment: Yes, chaos thus far

Comment: But, this is not FULLY correct :(

Comment: ALL THE CHAOS! Checkmarked! PS I love that “Not So Partial Answer”!